# 複数タグ検索で一致した数を元に記事をソートしたい

Tags: mysql

MySQLデータベースに、記事テーブル posts とタグを表す tags、中間テーブルの post_tag の３つのテーブルが有ります。
記事には複数のタグを持ち、タグは複数の記事に属します。
post_tag は post_id, tag_id というカラムでそれぞれをつないでいます。

タグ 1, 2, 3 で検索した時、３つのタグをすべて持っている記事は 3、一致するタグが２つだけの時は 2 となるようなクエリはどのように書いたら良いのでしょうか？

参考までに現状の３つのタグのいずれかを含む記事を得るクエリを掲載しておきます。

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
JOIN post_tag ON posts.id = post_tag.post_id
JOIN tags ON post_tag.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.id IN(1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY posts.id
```

MySQLのバージョンは 5.5 です。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 文中にある「３つのタグをすべて持っている記事は 3、一致するタグが２つだけの時は 2 となるようなクエリ」と「タグ別の一致数(を得るためのクエリ)」はそれぞれ意味が異なるのではないかと思いましたが、実際には同じクエリを想定していますか？

Comment: 「３つのタグをすべて持っている記事は 3、一致するタグが２つだけの時は 2 となるようなクエリ」のほうだけが必要です。紛らわしかったので後者の記述は削除しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id), p.* FROM posts p
JOIN post_tag pt ON p.id = pt.post_id 
JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY p.id;
```

結合した結果`post`と`tag`の組み合わせ総数が求まるので、あとは`post`ごとに数をカウントすればよいかと思います。
質問文中のクエリで問題無さそうに見えますが、もしかすると単に `posts.id = posts.id` の部分でtypoしているせいで想定外の結果になっているのかもしれません。

Comment: こちらの場合に posts の持つ title や created_at などのカラムの取得を行う際、「JOIN posts ON s.postid = posts.id」のようにして再度JOINしてしまえば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 当初の回答、推敲できていませんでしたので文中クエリを書き直しました。

Comment: 「pt.post_id = t.id」の部分を修正していただいてもよろしいでしょうか？こちらからでは編集できませんでした。

Comment: 不必要に混乱させてしまい申し訳ありません、修正しました。typoを指摘しておきながら自身もtypoしていました。

Answer (score 2):

既に解決済みではありますが、、

`post_tag`テーブルが`tag_id`を持っているので、`tags`テーブルを結合する必要はありません。
（`post_tag`テーブルが`tags`テーブルに存在しない`tag_id`を持っている可能性があるなら、話は別ですが。）

以下のSQL文で十分です。

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM posts AS p 
INNER JOIN post_tag AS pt ON p.post_id = pt.post_id 
WHERE pt.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY p.post_id 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56283/1

ただし、上のSQL文では一致するタグ数が同じレコードの並び順は不定となります。
その並び順を制御したい場合は、`ORDER BY`句に必要な条件を追加してください。

また、取得するデータに一致したタグの数を含めたくない場合、以下のように書けます。

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts AS p 
INNER JOIN post_tag AS pt ON p.post_id = pt.post_id 
WHERE pt.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY p.post_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```